# MOD_REWRITE recipe: /agencyname TO /appname/login.jsp?a=agencyname

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-2.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask)

I am looking for a recipe for a mod_rewrite rule that will accomplish this:

MOD_REWRITE recipe:  /agencyname  TO  /appname/login.jsp?a=agencyname

Comment: I am going to have to re-enter this one because it doesn't answer my question and neither does the reference as a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)        /appname/login.jsp?a=$1
```

should be your solution.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I created a directory called "appname" off the root of my site and then tried your rule with http://localhost/appname  but all it does is show me the contents of the "appname" directory.  The rule doesn't fire.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question since it doesnt cover the case if someone entered /appname/xxxx  as the URI.  in that case i would still only want to pass "appname".

Comment: @djangofan well that requirement wasn't in your question. We're not mind readers. And yes, @Stefan's solution is correct. There may be something wrong with how you're testing it, though.